# Python error when using os.popen()

Tags: python, macos, svn, popen

Well, I have a python script running on Mac OS X. Now I need to modify it to support updating my SVN working copy into a specified time. However, after learning I've found that SVN commands only support updating the working copy into a specified version.

So I write a function to grub the information from the command: svn log XXX, to find the corresponding version to the specified time. Here is my solution:

```
process=os.popen('svn log XXX')
print process.readline()
print process.readline()
process.close()
```

To make the problem simple, I just print the first 2 lines in the output. However, when I was executing the script, I got the error message: svn: Write error: Broken pipe

I think that the reason why I got the message is that the svn command kept executing when I was closing the Popen. So the error message arise.

Is there any one who can help me slove the problem? Or give me a alternative solution to reach the goal. Thx!

Comment: Have you considered using pysvn instead?

Comment: Also, `os.popen` has been replaced by `subprocess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get that error whenever I use `svn log | head`, too, it's not Python specific. Try something like:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

process = Popen('svn log XXX', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
print process.stdout.readline()
print process.stdout.readline()
```

to suppress the `stderr`. You could also just use

```
stdout, stderr = Popen('svn log XXX | head -n2', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
print stdout
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use pysvn. It is quite easy to use. Or use subprocess.

Does you error still occur if you do finally:

```
print process.read()
```

And it is better to call wait() if you use os.popen or subprocess.

Comment: In Python read() reads all output until the file handle gets closed. If a subprocess writes some bytes, waits two hours and again writes some bytes and exists, the parent process doing a read() will wait the whole time.